# Dhcpd: I have 2 Linux Ubuntu Servers running DHCP. Is it possible to install a 3rd DHCP server (which will run Windows Server)?

Tags: dhcp, dhcpd

Im learning /etc/dhcpd.conf, and set up 2 dhcp servers that are running Ubuntu 1204. Do you know if I can make a 3rd dhcp server, but I want this one to run Windows DHCP (not AD, just Dhcp and download zone updates from the Ubuntu dhcp servers)?

Comment: I think theres something wrong with your terminology. You can't mean DHCP since a DHCP server doesn't run Ubuntu or Windows. A Ubuntu or Windows server can run a DHCP daemon. Also more than one DHCP in your network will f*** it up.

Comment: Correct. I am running a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server1 with the Dhcpd Service enabled and configured. I am copying the /etc/dhcpd.conf to the Server2 (ubuntu) to make it a secondary zone (Dhcp Relay). I would like to add a third Dhcp Server3-Win, but use Windows Server to run the DHCP Service and sync the dhcpd.conf from the Ubuntu Servers. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can - and for larger networks possibly should - run multiple DHCP servers on the same network. When the client send out the DHCPDiscover request, it simply chooses from the replies it receives from each server - almost always the first one it receives. For it to work properly, the servers must handle separate ranges of addresses. As long as you manage the ranges / scopes correctly, the platform (Windows / Ubuntu) shouldn't matter

Comment: Thanks so much, sorry for the beginner question. So... does this mean that a DHCP Ubuntu Server will work on the same VLAN as a DHCP Windows Server, and that the clients will randomly be assigned a address from either of those servers?

Comment: Yes. You can have multiple DHCP servers in the same VLAN - but you must make sure they don't hand out IPs from the same ranges. When teaming multiple Windows DHCP servers, I believe you can get them handing out IPs from the same ranges, but they will track each other so it isn't an issue. Not sure how you'd achieve that with a combo of NIX and Win though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple DHCP servers in the same network segment as long as they are each aware of the address ranges / scope being used and that overlaps are managed properly.